# How to resolve MSBuild throws Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Scripts\dist\main.bundle.js" because it was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, angular-cli, azure-pipelines, msbuild-task

Azure Pipeline project has two Build Agents

1. Build Angular Project.

Builds successfully and assets, chunk.js files and bundle.js files published as Artifacts

2. Build ASP.net Web Application.

I download the Artifacts from previous build agents and extract them inside the **$(build.stagingDirectory)/Scripts/dist** directory since they will be consumed by the ASP.net project.

My **Extract files** task ymal is

```
steps:
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  displayName: 'Extract files bundle.zip'
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/dist/$(Build.BuildId)_bundle.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)/Scripts/dist'
```

When the **MSBuild** build the ASP.net project it is not able to find the `##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Scripts\dist\main.bundle.js" because it was not found.`

MS Build yaml is :

```
steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution NMG.Portal.MVCForAngular'
  inputs:
    solution: NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular/NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular.csproj
    msbuildArguments: '/p:ProjectFile=$(build.sourcesDirectory)\NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular\NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)\\"'
    clean: false
    logProjectEvents: true
    createLogFile: true
```

My ASP.NET BundleConfig.cs file has bellow code.

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/nmg").Include(
                "~/Scripts/dist/inline*",
                "~/Scripts/dist/polyfills*",
                "~/Scripts/dist/scripts*",
                "~/Scripts/dist/vendor*",
                "~/Scripts/dist/main*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/nmg").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/dist/styles*"));
        }
    }
```

Logically this should work.

I would like to know what is missing here? Why the MSBuild could not find the bundles that i extracted inside the Scripts/dist.

The main.bundle.js that is copied to Scripts/dist folder is main.7515c53aa0f2ef625908.bundle.js but MSBuild does not consider it.

Comment: I think you should extract the bundle to `$(build.sourcesDirectory)/NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular/Scripts/dist` and not to your `$(build.stagingDirectory)/Scripts/dist`

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now as expected it is coping under Extracting file: D:\a\1\dist\90_bundle.zip
[command]D:\a\_tasks\ExtractFiles_5e1e3830-fbfb-11e5-aab1-090c92bc4988\1.151.1\7zip\7z.exe x -oD:\a\1\s\NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular\Scripts\dist D:\a\1\dist\90_bundle.zip.

But still the build fails with same message as previous.

Comment: I still feel, it is just a wrong path reference to the file. This can only be validated with the help of log. Could you please post the relevant parts of the log from the extract task and your build task. (enable verbose to see all actions for the build task)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actual issue was that when the MSBuild creates the publish files it copies files base on the build definition. I edited the .csproj file as bellow which copied the relevant files.

```
<Content Include="assets\i18n\**" />    
<Content Include="Scripts\dist\*.bundle.js" />
<Content Include="Scripts\dist\*.bundle.css" />
<Content Include="*.chunk.js" />
```

This was possible since, prior to the MSBuild task I did copy the angular files to the relevant folders.

Comment: This was a lifesaver, thank you. I had accidentally forgot to check this file in, which lead to all my builds on the build server failing. I had removed some files and the build server kept looking for the removed files, and it turned out that the reason was that they were still referenced in the .csproj file of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with **Thangadurai**, this could be a path-related issue.

Check `$(build.sourcesDirectory)/Scripts/dist`, `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` normally represents the solution directory. So now your file structure is something like this:

```
`$(build.sourcesDirectory)`(sln directory)
    |
    Scripts
    |    |
    |    ----dist
    |           |
    |            ----main.xxx.bundle.js
    |       
    xx.sln
    |
    NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular
         |
         NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular.csproj
         |
         Scripts
```

The extracted main.xx.js is placed in Script folder in Solution directory, however, msbuild will search for the Script folder in Project directory when `msbuild + NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular.csproj`.

**In addition:** I suggest you check if there exists reference to `Scripts\dist\main.bundle.js` in the content of `NMG.WebApp.MVCForAngular.csproj`, if it exists, you also need to make sure the extracted filename matches the reference in project file perfectly.

Msbuild won't consider `main.7515c53aa0f2ef625908.bundle.js` and `main.bundle.js` the same one, so you'll also get that error if the name of extract-file doesn't match the reference in project file.

Comment: Your are correct in one way. The folder structure was wrong. Event though as you mentioned the main.7515c53aa0f2ef625908.bundle.js will be opt out in the MSBuild. Hence I edited the .csproj file to include the files in the script/dist folder. Please refer to my answer bellow.

Comment: Here I am building the project not the solution. So the files are copied to the correct location.

Comment: @Desmond Hi friend, glad to know you've found the solution and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members to search this useful information more easily, it just a reminder :)